# Ensure asynchronous loading of files and execution of functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, react-helmet

I'm taking over [a website](https://www.10studio.tech/docs/prettyFormula/) by [V2 Docusaurus](https://v2.docusaurus.io/).

One particularity of our website is that we need to load [office.js](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js) and [css-vars-ponyfill.min.js](https://unpkg.com/css-vars-ponyfill@2/dist/css-vars-ponyfill.min.js), and run some functions in [patches.js](https://www.10studio.tech/lib/patches.js) in the very beginning. So the previous developer decided to use the following approach.

In every `.mdx.md` page, he wrapped the content by a component `MainWrapper`:

```
<MainWrapper>
    ... ...
    Real content
    ... ...
</MainWrapper>
```

`MainWrapper/index.js` is defined as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from '@docusaurus/Head';

function MainWrapper(props) {
    return (<>
        <Head>
            <script
                src="/lib/patches.js" 
                onload="(function(){console.log('patches.js has been fully loaded')}).call(this)" >
            </script>
            <script async defer 
                src='https://unpkg.com/css-vars-ponyfill@2/dist/css-vars-ponyfill.min.js'
                onload="(function(){console.log('css-vars-ponyfill.min.js has been fully loaded'); onCssVarsPonyfillLoad();}).call(this)">
            </script>
            <script async defer 
                src='https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js'
                onload="(function(){console.log('office.js has been fully loaded'); onOfficejsLoad();}).call(this)">
            </script>
        </Head>
        {props.children}
    </>)
}

export default MainWrapper;
```

`lib/Patches.js` contains real operations:

```
var pushStateRef = history.pushState;
var replaceStateRef = history.replaceState;

console.log("already inside patches.js")
console.log("history.pushSate and replaceState have been saved")

function patch() {
    if (!history.pushState) {
        history.pushState = pushStateRef;
        history.replaceState = replaceStateRef;
        console.log("history.pushState and replaceState have been set back")
    };
}

... ...

function onCssVarsPonyfillLoad() {
    console.log("already inside patches.js > onCssVarsPonyfillLoad()")
    ... ...
}

function onOfficejsLoad() {
    Office.onReady(function () {
        console.log("already inside Office.onReady");
        patch();
    })
}
```

My tests show that, sometimes, this implementation can ensure loading `patches.js` before `office.js` and `css-vars-ponyfill.min.js` as `<script async defer` do. However, sometimes, this order cannot be ensured:

[image]

`@docusarus/Head` uses `react-helmet`. Does anyone know how to fix this loading order problem? What I want is loading `patches.js` before anything else, is there any workaround?

Comment: Why does the order of loading matter as long as the order of execution is right?

Comment: Because there is something (about `pushState`) in `patches.js` that needs to be executed before loading `office.js` and executing `onOfficejsLoad()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to just put the whole code of `patches.js` inside `<script>... ...</script>` before the other files as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from '@docusaurus/Head';
import CssvarsWrapper from '../CssvarsWrapper';
import OfficejsWrapper from '../OfficejsWrapper';

class MainWrapper extends React.Component {        
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Head>
                    <script>{`
                        console.log("begin patches")
                        ... ... // the body of patches.js
                    `}</script>
                    <script async defer 
                        src='https://unpkg.com/css-vars-ponyfill@2/dist/css-vars-ponyfill.min.js'
                        onload="(function(){console.log('css-vars-ponyfill.min.js has been fully loaded'); onCssVarsPonyfillLoad();}).call(this)">
                    </script>
                    <script async defer 
                        src='https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js'
                        onload="(function(){console.log('office.js has been fully loaded'); onOfficejsLoad();}).call(this)">
                    </script>
                </Head>
                {this.props.children}
            </>
        )  
    }
}

export default MainWrapper;
```